# Jquery dropdown list

Tags: jquery, sql, drop-down-menu

Although I've populated a dropdown list from an SQL database before (along time ago, don't think I even remember how to do it) I now need some help with populating a dropdown list populated by the SQL database, then depending on what selection is selected, display the next dropdown list populated again by another table in the SQL database.

Can someone please help, ideally with a demo as It's been a longtime since I've done anything SQL.

Thanks

Comment: Search google and SO. There are a million examples out there. Will you be populating the select after the page load or before the page load? What Server Side language are you using? MySQL or MSSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very Easy!

```
<select name="ALBUM">
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `PHOTOALBUM` WHERE `USERNAME` = '{$Modules['User']->Username}' ;";
    $RESULTS = mysql_query($sql);
    while($ROW = mysql_fetch_assoc($RESULTS)) {
        echo '<option value="' . $ROW['ALBUM'] . '">' . $ROW['ALBUM'] . '</option>';
    }
</select>
```

this is one i use for one of the websites i created. It takes all of your photoalbums and creates a dropdown list of them to choose from when adding photos. hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but this par is not much of an issue really.

Comment: Sorry, was on another world when i wrote that, what you put is correct. Sorry